# Where is Contance Spano (David Levinson's wife) in Independence Day: Resurgence?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

Why wasn't Contance Spano, David Levinson's wife, in *Independence Day: Resurgence*? Did I miss a bit of exposition about her absence?

Answer (score 0):

In the novel *[Independence Day: Crucible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(book_series)#Independence_Day:_Crucible)*, which is set between the two films, she is revealed to have died in an automobile accident some time before February 2012.

> [...] he sat alone on the couch and he felt her absence. The lack of Connie.
>
> This time, saving the world wouldn’t be enough to get her back. He would have to rewind time itself, to the moment before the teenager in the SUV decided to send a text to his girlfriend, before he coasted through a red light at nearly eighty miles an hour. They had tried to comfort him by saying she probably never felt it, never knew what was happening. But he knew Connie would have wanted to see it coming.
>
> <sub>*Independence Day: Crucible* by Greg Keyes, chapter 24 "February 2012"</sub>